# Как вернуть значение в родительскую Activity при закрытии дочерней?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, activity, xamarin

Есть два Activity: на первой есть `Button` и `TextView`, на второй есть `Button` и `EditText`. Находясь на первой Activity пользователь нажимает на кнопку и открывается вторая Activity:

```
StartActivity(typeof(ListAddItemActivity));
```

На `ListAddItemActivity` пользователь вводит в `EditText` слово и нажимает на кнопку, тем самым закрывает Activity:

```
MyListActivity.Str = _str; // Статическое свойство 1-ой activity
Finish();
```

Надо, чтобы на первой отобразилось слово в `TextView`.

Куда надо поместить `myTextView.Text = Str;`, чтобы Activity это поняла при переходе на её с другой?
Надо как-то грамотно использовать `onPause()` и `onResume()`, но я никак не могу сообразить, как именно это реализовать.

Comment: Специально, чтобы передать какой-либо результат из `Activity2` обратно, в `Activity1` существуют методы `startActivityForResult()` и `onActivityResult()`. Как правильно их реализовать в Xamarin, я не знаю. Но гугл знает точно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [OnActivityResult](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_activity_for_result/) (этот метод должен быть в вашем первом `Activity`):

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
     var textViewFromFirstActivity = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textViewFromFirstActivity);
     textViewFromFirstActivity.Text = data.GetStringExtra("msg");
  }
}
```